How to get world coorditates from image coordinates (z=0)
I my camera captures the area on which the objects are located that is why I do not need "Z" coordinate. I recently have this code. I have 4 objects (qr codes, which are in fixed position) which I know their world and image coordinates. But my goal is this one: If I put any object somewhere between these 4 object, my camera takes a picture and my neural network gives me image coordinates of this new object, now I would like to know the world coordinates of this new object. How can I get it. Thank you so much.

Does this answer your question? Computing x,y coordinate (3D) from image point

you tagged "OpenCV". that other Q&A also uses opencv, just the original API instead of the Python wrapper. All the functions are the same.

The question is a little unclear. But if you're trying to get world coordinates from image coordinates then this question already covers the problem.
Just keep in mind that going from world to image space is a projection and the inverse of that is just another projection (called a backwards projection).
So if your image coordinates T \times P = I. Then you have I and you compute T, and T^{-1} \times T \times P = P. Here T is the projection matrix from world to camera, I is the projected image and P is a point in world coordinates
